# Writing to a file from multiple threads

Tags: jruby

I am trying to write out to a text file using multiple threads, however the code below gives me an exception - `IOError: closed stream`

```ruby
threads = []
File.open("test.txt", "a") do |fp|
  500.times do |time|
    threads << Thread.new do
      fp.puts("#{time}: 1")
      sleep(rand(100) / 100.0)
      fp.puts("#{time}: 2")
    end
  end
end

threads.each{ |thread| thread.join }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the join inside the file.open block:

```rb
threads = []
File.open("test.txt", "a") do |fp|
  500.times do |time|
    threads << Thread.new do
      fp.puts("#{time}: 1")
      sleep(rand(100) / 100.0)
      fp.puts("#{time}: 2")
    end
  end

  threads.each{ |thread| thread.join }
end
```

Why? `Thread.new` launches the thread, but it runs in parallel, and the life of the thread in your version isn't guaranteed to be shorter than the life of the file. `File.open` closes the file after you exit the attached block. By waiting to close the file until after all the threads are done, everything will work as expected.

However, please note that this *IS NOT* thread safe on JRuby (or any other implementation without a GIL) and may have output intermixed:

```
6: 1
5: 17: 1
8: 1

3: 10: 110: 1
4: 11: 1
2: 19: 1

11: 1



12: 1
13: 1
14: 1
```

Note: this question appears to be from [Ruby MRI 1.8.7 - File writing thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108424/ruby-mri-1-8-7-file-writing-thread-safety)

Comment: Thanks, for the purpose of what I'm doing writing in order isn't necessary so this works for me. Cheers!